# CodeShip: Cannot load such file -- 'sinatra/base'

Tags: sinatra, rake, codeship

I was trying to run my tests through CodeShip and somehow it doesn't allow me to setup my test environment.

My config scripts are:

```
rvm use 2.4 --install
bundle install
rake db:create RACK_ENV=test
rake db:migrate RACK_ENV=test
rake db:seed RACK_ENV=test
```

My test script is simply `rake test`

My Rakefile looks like this:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
require 'sinatra/flash'
require 'sinatra/cookies'
require 'require_all'
require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new { |t| t.pattern = 'spec/*/*_spec.rb' }
```

And somehow CodeShip keeps complaining that it cannot load 'sinatra/base' from my Rakefile even though it has been installed onto the VM. `rake test` also runs fine on my local machine so I have no idea what went wrong there.

Can anyone suggests what happened? Thanks.

Comment: Marko, from the Codeship team here. Did you already reach out to our helpdesk at https://helpdesk.codeship.com? We'd like to help you solve this, but from the top of my head the only idea I have right now is that you might need to `require rubygems` as well?

Comment: @mlocher Thanks for reaching out! I haven't contacted the helpdesk yet. I am using a newer ruby version so I believe `require rubygems` is not required for the setup?

Comment: Yeah, it shouldn't, but it was the only thing that came to my mind.

Could I ask you to reach out via https://helpdesk.codeship.com and include a link to your project (or a specific build), we'd be happy to help you get to the bottom of this.